# How to create an array with random numbers and send it to listener without randomizing it again?

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface, listener, actionlistener

So i'm trying to create a program that create an array of 100 random numbers (without changing everytime user reacts to it), and allow users to check the numbers by entering the index of it. However, the array keep randomizing everytime the user pressed the Show Element button.

I also tried to create the array on the main program, but I then faced the error because the listener can't access the array. Please enlighten me as I'm new to this Java GUI Programming. Any help is much appreciated.

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class P3Q2 extends JFrame {

    private JTextField text1 = new JTextField(10);
    private JTextField text2 = new JTextField(10);
    private int arr[];

    private JButton jbtShow = new JButton("Show Element");

    public P3Q2() {
        JPanel jpTextField = new JPanel();
        jpTextField.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2));
        jpTextField.add(new JLabel("Array Index"));
        jpTextField.add(text1);
        jpTextField.add(new JLabel("Array Element"));
        jpTextField.add(text2);
        text2.setEditable(false);

        JPanel jpButtons = new JPanel();
        jpButtons.add(jbtShow);

        add(jpTextField);
        add(jpButtons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        jbtShow.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

        setTitle("Display: Show Bounds Error");
        setSize(400, 150);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                Random rd = new Random(); // creating Random object
                int[] arr = new int[100];
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    arr[i] = rd.nextInt(); // storing random integers in an array
                }

                if (e.getSource() == jbtShow) {
                    int num = Integer.parseInt(text1.getText());
                    int result = arr[num];
                    text2.setText("" + result);
                }
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
                text2.setText("Out of bound!");
            }

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        P3Q2 test = new P3Q2();
    }
}
```

Comment: each time you click your button, the code in the actionPerformed is executed. Of course will that re-create a random array. the array you create in your actionperformed is also a local variable, which is not related to the other one

Comment: @Stultuske yep thats the exact problem I'm trying to solve, can you guide me where should I put the loop so that it won't re-create the array?

Comment: You already create an array in your constructor. Why do you need to create another one, if you don't intend to?

Comment: @Stultuske My apologies I didn't post the updated code, I edited the code you can check it now. I removed the loop in the constructor part as if I place it there the listener cannot access the array and it shows the NullPointerException error.

Comment: I don't see why the listener's method should throw a NPE, because in both you use a local variable arr, not the actual instance variable

Comment: @Stultuske the solution below actually solved my problem, I believe it is because I overridden the arr declaration as I already declared it as private int arr[]; but on the array part I declared it again. Anyways I truly appreciate your time and help, please have a good day m8 !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the constructor you are assigning the random numbers to a **local variable arr** that is overriding the **private attribute arr** with the same name

Try changing it to:

```
Random rd = new Random(); // creating Random object
arr = new int[100];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = rd.nextInt(); // storing random integers in an array
}
```

Comment: Thanks m8 for the enlightment! I removed the loop on the second part and remove the "int" and it worked like a charm! Have a good day ahead!

Answer (score 0):

Although you are shadowing your `arr` field you are still creating a new array each time an event is processed which is something you said you didn't want to do.

Doing significant processing in the Event Dispatch Thread is not a good idea.  It can tie up the GUI.  Even though you're only generating 100 random numbers I recommend initializing the array and then just reusing it.

You can do that by having an initialization block in your `ButtonListener` class.  Then subsequent events will simply use that array without recreating it. The array will be created upon instantiation of your `ButtonListener`.

```
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    private int arr[] = new int[100];
    {
        Random rd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = rd.nextInt(); // storing random integers in an array
            
        }
    }
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            if (e.getSource() == jbtShow) {
                int num = Integer.parseInt(text1.getText());
                int result = arr[num];
                text2.setText("" + result);
            }
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
            text2.setText("Out of bound!");
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to access `arr` outside of the listener you can use your existing array declaration of `private int[] arr;` and simply use that in the `ButtonListener` class.

Another observation.  Catching an exception would be a good idea for `parseInt` since the value might not be a number.  But if the parsing is acceptable, why not just check to ensure it is between `0 and arr.length-1` inclusive?